# SharePoint mapped Layouts/15/Images folder/image.jpg - not showing up

Tags: sharepoint-server, layouts

In my SharePoint 2013 site, where I am deploying few of the images in the layouts/Images/Test and when I am trying to access it on sharepoint, I am just seeing an 'X' mark. Where as there are few other images in the same folder and accessed similarly(/_layouts/15/Images/Test/testImage5.jpg) and I am able to see those images. But this newly added image is just showing up as cross mark.

Kindly suggest What can be the issue.

Comment: Its happening to you only or all users. May be browser cache issue.

Comment: What method are you using to deploy images to the layouts folder?  Are you packaging a solution and deploying a .wsp package, or using a powershell copy command, or manually copying to the layouts folder on the web server using (or other I have not mentioned)?

Comment: Currently I am directly deploying from Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please ensure you are referring correct Web Application(where your
   images are deployed).
2. Navigate to IIS and Locate the file path in
   Web App -> right-click -> browse, check URL is correct (replace
   localhost to web app url)

Answer (score 0):

Use developer tool to check the image full url, and then request the url in a new tab of browser, if the image couldn't show, the image url would not correct.

Use IIS manager to confirm the path also.

[image]